# Is there a regular language and irregular language that can be unioned to get a regular language?

Tags: computer-science

I am taking cs 252 and this is a question that was mentioned and im kind of stuck on it. It is my understanding that if an irregular language is unioned with a regular language, then the resultant is irregular. Ive tried making the regular language cancel out the irregular part of the irregular language (having one be a^n b^n and the other be a^1/n or something like that but then both of the labguages would be regular… any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your regular language could be every possible string.  Σ<sup>*</sup> where Σ is your alphabet.

Then unioning this with anything just gives you back everything.

And if your next question is going to be about intersection, then of course the answer is the regular language that contains no strings whatsoever.

Comment: Did this answer your question?